# Using python to take a 32x32 matrices append many of these matrices to a single array then adding a timestamp index to each matrix

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am very new to coding python and I am working with a .CSV file that gives me a 32x32 matrix in a 1024 column row with a time stamp. I reshaped the data to give me 32x32 arrays and looped through each row appending the matrices to a numpy array.

```
`i = 0 
while i < len(df_array):
    if i == 0:
    spec = np.reshape(df_array[i][np.arange(1,1025)], (32,32))
    spectrum_matrix = spec
else: 
    spec = np.reshape(df_array[i][np.arange(1,1025)], (32,32))
    spectrum_matrix = np.concatenate((spectrum_matrix, spec), axis = 0)
i = i + 1
print("job done")`
```

What I would like to do is to add the time stamp from the original data file and add them to each of the matrices thus allowing me to re sample the data over a 5 minute average. I also would like to plot the bins a to get a plot similar to this [Drop size distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gquIx.png)

As a  reference I am reading in the data .CSV with pandas and here is an example of a portion of the raw data: 01.06.2017;18:22:20;0.122;0.00;51;7.401;10375;18745;57;27;0.00;23.6;0.110;0;
 <SPECTRUM>;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

The ;'s after the SPECTRUM is the 32x32 matrix.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: so your entire dataset is 1024x32x32? what does '32x32 matrix in a 1024 column row with a timestamp' mean?

Comment: the data set is 8640x1024 actually, the each one of the 1024 columns is a "bin" that was part of a 32x32 matrix before the data got exported in the .CSV format. Basically there is 32 velocities bins and 32 diameter bins which are "filled" with data during a 10second poll. At the end of each poll you are given a date and time i.e. 01.06.2017;18:22:20;... And I want to have the date and time index with every matrix so I can plot a time series of Dropsize distrubtion throughout a day. I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: So in a ten second period velocity and diameter are measure 32 time each? Where does 8640 come from?
Sorry for these questions, but it's important to know how the data is structured when you receive it and how you want your final output to be structured.

Comment: The 8640 rows from each time step i.e. 00:0010.....23:59:50 ( 6 polls every minute * 60 min/hour * 24 hours/day). and what is being measured is precip size and velocity during the 10 second poll, so if 15 5mm drops fall at 5 m/s during the 10s poll you'll get 15 in the 5mm-5m/s bin. There are 1024 of these bins corresponding to all 32 velocity and 32 diameter combination (32x32=1024)

Comment: maybe provide a sample of the data, the explanation is rather confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Python and associated packages can do many things without loops

From my understanding of your data you have a (8640 x 32 x 32) Data Structure (time x size x velocity).
Pandas works very well with 2D data structures, however for higher dimensional data I would recommend you get familiar with [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/why-xarray.html). With this package along with pandas you can create and manipulate your data without having to resort to loops.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

#create random data
data = (np.random.binomial(n =5, p  =0.2, size =(8640,32,32))*1000).astype(int)

#create labels for data
sizes= np.linspace(1,5,32)
velocities = np.linspace(1,1000, num = 32)

#make time range of 24 hours with 10sec intervals
ind = pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01', periods=8640, freq='10s') 

#convert data to xarray 3D data structure
df = xr.DataArray(data, coords = [ind, sizes, velocities], 
                  dims = ['time', 'size', 'speed'])

#make a 5 min average of the data
min_average= df.resample('300s', dim = 'time', how = 'mean')

#plot sample of data and 5 min average
my1d = min_average.isel(size = 5, speed= 10)
my1d.plot(label = '5 min avg')
plt.gca()
df.isel(size = 5, speed =10).plot(alpha = 0.3, c = 'r', label = 'raw_data')
plt.legend()
```

[image: example plot of your data]

---

As for making a distribution plot like you linked things become a bit trickier but is possible:

```
#transform your data to only have mean speed for each time and size
#and convert to pandas dataframe
mean_speed =min_average.mean(dim = ['speed'])
#for some reason xarray make you name the new column when you convert
#to a pandas dataframe. I then get rid of the extra empty variable with 
#a list comprehension
df= mean_speed.to_dataframe('').unstack().T
df.index =  np.array([np.array(i)[1].astype(float) for i in df.index])

#make a contourplot of your new data
plt.contourf(df.columns, df.index, df.values, cmap ='PuBu_r')
plt.title('mean speed')
plt.ylabel('size')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]